# Version of parent module in child modules specified in profiles not getting updated by Maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a multimodule project with one module that is slow to build and only used when releasing (release-only). In the an aggregate pom i have all modules specified besides the release-only module. The release-only module is specified in a seperate profile which i activate with the maven-release-plugin and it builds it and release it fine.

The problem is the version of the parent module in the release-only module does not get updated when i run release:prepare, meaning while all other modules build (in both prepare, and perform) with the parent artifact version set correctly, the release-only module still has -SNAPSHOT in the version.

I found this what seems to be related issue. But no sollution.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-843

Some simplyfied code from the aggregate pom, explaining the structure.

```
<profile>
<id>build-rpm</id>
 <modules>
   <module>release-only</module>
 </modules>
</profile>

<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
 <configuration>
   <releaseProfiles>build-rpm</releaseProfiles>
 </configuration>
</plugin>

<modules>
  <module>module1</module>
  <module>module2</module>
</modules>
```

When running mvn release:prepare i want the versions in all my modules to be updated. (Like the normal  mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=xxx which work as expected)

neither mvn release:update-versions
and mvn release:prepare update the versions as expected.

Comment: Never use modules in profiles...Really bad idea https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/ Furthermore the question is: What exactly is slow in the module ? I suppose your tests/integration tests ?

Comment: Yes, its just mainly the fact that it is 100% unecessary to build this module any other time then in release as its building an RPM package which we use for installing, and its very slow process.

Thanks for the information, ill check that post out as it looks like it could solve my question.

Comment: The simple trick is not to exclude the module by a profile instead you should make a profile inside the module. That will prevent you from such issues.

Comment: Yes, i got this working and would mark your comment as anwser if i could! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple trick is not to exclude the module by a profile instead you should make a profile inside the module. That will prevent you from such issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to remove the "slow module" from the multi-module build. Instead, create a pipeline in your build server (Jenkins, Bamboo, whatever) that first builds your multi-module project and then (in the case of a release) builds the "slow module".

This way, you avoid all the hassle with modules in profiles and switching modules off and on.